# how to send select_tag value in form parameter in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, form-submit, selectionchanged, html-select

```
<%= form_tag url_for(new_manage_listing_media_path(3)),:method => 'get' do -%>
   <%= label_tag ':name', "Choose media:" %>      
   <%= select_tag "id", options_from_collection_for_select(@listing, "id", "name")%>
   <%= submit_tag("OK") %>
<% end %>
```

actually what i want is in `form_tag url_for(new_manage_listing_media_path(3))`, instead of 3 i want to put the `select_tag`'s selected value.

Thanks,
ariv

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JavaScript to do what you're saying. Add an onUpdate handler to the select field, and update the action attribute for the form.

However, I think you can just leave out the three, and then the `id` value from the select will be used instead. Otherwise, name the `select_tag` something else, like `lookup_id` and use `Model.find(params[:id] || params[:lookup_id])` in the controller, where `Model` is the model you're looking up.